# How to run protractor starting with node command?

Tags: node.js, protractor

I am looking for a way, where i can run Protractor program by starting from node command.
Something like:- *node protractor conf.js* instead of *protractor conf.js*

Comment: Why do you want to run it as a node command? Can you please update your question with the necessary details? Thanks

Comment: @GirishSortur That way you can control which node executable is being used. There could be many on the system.

Answer (score 2):

For local installation:

```
$ node node_modules/.bin/protractor conf.js
```

For global installation (*Linux*, *Mac*):

```
$ node $(which protractor) conf.js
```

---

*npm* moves executable files, which represent a package, to `node_modules/.bin` directory after package installation. Most of the times it is an executable JS file, you'll be fine passing it directly to *node*. Pretty the same logic is behind a global installation, but in this case you don't know actual path to the executable. There is a utility command `which` for *Linux* and *Macs* - it returns a path to a binary for a globally available command, in my case it returns:

```
$ which protractor
$ /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/bin/protractor
```

It is possible to evaluate a sub-expression using `$(some expression)`, so *node* will receive a path to executable, so the result would be:

```
$ node /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/bin/protractor conf.js
```